# Flow of showBack of form

Tags: codenameone

I am using `preForm.showBack();` and the previous form is displayed but I did not understand of Flow of the form. Which method of the form is called when the `showBack(`) is called (beforeForm,postForm or else).

I have InfiniteContainer in previous and after showBack fetchComponents of container is called , how is it called?

Answer (score 0):

`show` & `showBack` are methods of the form itself that work directly unaware of the state machine in the old GUI builder. You need to call `back()` if you are using the old GUI builder so the navigation occurs thru the state machine and unwinds the navigation stack.

At that point the right callback methods will be performed.

`showBack` "works" because it returns to the last instance of the form which was initialized beforehand.

Comment: As per I understand when showback() is called, previous state of the previous form is displayed .
1. But how is the fetchComponents method of InfiniteContainer called after showback()  ?
2. And how can the calling fetchComponent method be disabled after showback ?

Comment: `fetchComponents` is unrelated to back/forward navigation. It's part of the infinite scroll API

Comment: 1. why fetchComponents  is called ?
2. how can it be disabled only on back navigation ?

Comment: It's unrelated to back navigation. If you want to disable it when navigating back just change a state to indicate you are in back and implement `fetchComponents` so it returns null